# “Take the time” meaning

Tags: meaning, verbs, meaning-in-context

The following sentence comes from Charles Fennyhough's [*The Voices Within: The History and Science of How we Talk to Ourselves*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=0XT3CgAAQBAJ&pg=PT208&lpg=PT208&dq=Take+the+time+Adam+was+talking+to+a+member+of+his+mental+health+team+and+saying,+%E2%80%98I+would+be+terrified+to+be+a+schizophrenic%E2%80%99.&source=bl&ots=dVo6dle1cx&sig=Bq6Uy74wLNPhho8UGP7Ip-n1MXw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiCuYH_783cAhWOyaQKHaPXCzIQ6AEwAHoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=Take%20the%20time%20Adam%20was%20talking%20to%20a%20member%20of%20his%20mental%20health%20team%20and%20saying%2C%20%E2%80%98I%20would%20be%20terrified%20to%20be%20a%20schizophrenic%E2%80%99.&f=false):

> Take the time Adam was talking to a member of his mental health team and saying, ‘I would be terrified to be a schizophrenic’.

I don't understand what starting a sentence with "take the time" means. Could you help me please?

Comment: It means "Think of the time when Adam was talking...". The first _take_ is used in the same way as "Take, for example, this boat. It is yellow."

Comment: To be clear, "take the time" has at least two distinct meanings, which I think is causing the OP's confusion. This sentence is not using the "spend enough time [to do something well]" meaning, but can be paraphrased as "Consider the occasion Adam was talking..."

Comment: Tske, for instance, that time when Adam was talking ...

Comment: Yeah that's a garden-path sentence alright. Tripped me up as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Take" in this usage means "consider," as [@oerkelens](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/54363/oerkelens) commented.

This is distinct from a more common meaning of "take the time" which usually means "spend the time" as [@JonLarby](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/162337/jonlarby) commented.

And as [@Jim](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/17956/jim) commented, it's easiest to think of "consider" if you include the implied "for instance" and that "the time when" is implying a specific instance that might more clearly be referred to as "that time when." With these implications explicitly spelled out as @Jim did, you get "Take, for instance, that time when Adam was talking..."

FYI, there's [a related question about punctuating this usage of "take" as "consider."](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/240391/take-consider-as-an-example-vs-take-consider-for-example)